Hint for question about regarding elementary substructures in Kirby's Introduction to Model Theory
I am stuck on the $\varphi(\mathcal B)\subseteq\varphi(\mathcal A)$ part of the following question in Jonathan Kirby's model theory book: "Assume that $\mathcal A\preceq\mathcal B$ and that $\varphi(x)$ is an $L$-formula. Show that if $\varphi(\mathcal B)$ is finite then $\varphi(\mathcal A)=\varphi(\mathcal B)$, and if $\varphi(\mathcal B)$ is infinite, then $\varphi(\mathcal A)$". Here $\varphi(\mathcal B)$ means $\{b\in B:\mathcal B\models\varphi(b)\}$. Could someone give a hint? Thanks.

Hint: Say $n=|\varphi(\mathcal{B})|$. Write a formula $\psi$ saying "There exist $n$ elements $x$ satisfying $\varphi(x)$". By elementarity (in fact, elementary equivalence is enough for this part), $|\varphi(\mathcal{A})|\ge n$. Now, if $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets with $X\subset Y$ and $|X|=|Y|$, then $X=Y$.

@Reveillark Why not post this as an answer? The question is only asking for a hint.

@Reveillark Thank you very much, I got it now.

Hint: Say $n=|\varphi(\mathcal{B})|$. Write a formula $\phi$ saying "There exist $$ elements $$ satisfying $()$". By elementarity (in fact, elementary equivalence is enough for this part), $|(\mathcal{A})|≥$. Now, if  and  are finite sets with ⊂ and ||=||, then =.
